# Installing Repo

Tags: ppa, repository, executable

I have installed repo and created the ~/bin etc.

However, when I open the bin folder the repo is a gedit file, how do I make it so that the file is executable?

Comment: http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Comment: /home/cod3boy/bin/repo: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/home/cod3boy/bin/repo: line 1: `<!DOCTYPE html>'                                                             I have done nothing incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Give executable permission to ~/bin/repo,

```
chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
```

Comment: already have done that and it does not work it executes at gedit...

Comment: did you download repo from git-repo-downloads?

Comment: I have it installed from the ppa

Comment: see this http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Comment: perhaps the error I am receiving with will you              /home/cod3boy/bin/repo: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/home/cod3boy/bin/repo: line 1: `<!DOCTYPE html>'

Comment: open the repo file using gedit and delete the unexpected token as indicated in the error message.